# How to validate SQL Script in azure Devops

Tags: sql, azure-devops

I want to validate SQL scripts (No Syntax errors of SQL) in Azure DevOps.
I have added one task MSBuild@1 which validates my SQL scripts but gives a lot of non-required errors like `Only One Statement is required per batch. Batch Separator, such as 'Go' required between statements`.

I have written one update statement still it gives me above mentioned error and when I search for such an error people are recommended not to build a database project.

Is there any other alternative way of compiling my SQL scripts which will give only required syntax errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Unload SQL project in Visual studio
2. In your *.SqlProj file, you under `<PropertyGroup>`, add:
   `<SuppressTSqlWarnings>SQL71006</SuppressTSqlWarnings>`

**SQL71006** is the code for the warning/error statement you are getting MSBuild - `Only One Statement is required per batch. Batch Separator, such as 'Go' required between statement`.

For multiple error/warning codes suppression:

1. In visual studio SQL project, go to project properties, click on Build.
2. Under "Suppress Transact-SQL warnings", type warning numbers (without 'SQL') in comma separated format.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hope this will give me only the required actual SQL syntax errors.

Comment: Still I can see errors for SQL71006